# Scikit mean shift algorithm returns black picture

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, scikit-image, mean-shift

I am trying to perform image segmentation using scikit mean shift algorithm. I use opencv to display the segmented image.
My problem is the following: I use the code as given in different examples, and when I display the image after segmentation, I get a black image. I was wondering if someone could see what my mistake is...
Thanks a lot for the help !

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np    
import cv2    
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

#Loading original image
originImg = cv2.imread('Swimming_Pool.jpg')

# Shape of original image    
originShape = originImg.shape


# Converting image into array of dimension [nb of pixels in originImage, 3]
# based on r g b intensities    
flatImg=np.reshape(originImg, [-1, 3])


# Estimate bandwidth for meanshift algorithm    
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(flatImg, quantile=0.1, n_samples=100)    
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth = bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)

# Performing meanshift on flatImg    
ms.fit(flatImg)

# (r,g,b) vectors corresponding to the different clusters after meanshift    
labels=ms.labels_

# Remaining colors after meanshift    
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_    

# Finding and diplaying the number of clusters    
labels_unique = np.unique(labels)    
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)    
print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)    

# Displaying segmented image    
segmentedImg = np.reshape(labels, originShape[:2])    
cv2.imshow('Image',segmentedImg)    
cv2.waitKey(0)    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format code, I don't know how to write it correctly.

Comment: there is a button in the editor to format as code

Answer (score 1):

For **Displaying the image**, the correct code would be

```
segmentedImg = cluster_centers[np.reshape(labels, originShape[:2])]
cv2.imshow('Image',segmentedImg.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried your method of segmentation on a random sample photo, and the segmentation looked bad, probably because since your mean-shift is working only on the color space, it looses the locality info.  The python package skimage comes with a [segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html) module, and it offers a few super-pixel segmentation methods. The [quickshift](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.quickshift) method is based on the 'mode seeking' mechanism that meanshift is  based on. None of these methods would segment out an entire object in an image. They provide extremely localized segmentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to some other color-space (e.g., `Lab` colorspace, using the following code) and segment on the colors (discarding intensity).

```
from skimage.color import rgb2lab
image = rgb2lab(image)
```

Then use your above code to tune the parameters (`quantile` and `n_samples`) of the function `estimate_bandwidth()` and finally use `matplotlib`'s `subplot` to plot the segmented image as shown below:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(image), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('original image', size=20)
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(np.reshape(labels, image.shape[:2])), plt.axis('off'), plt.title('segmented image with Meanshift', size=20)
plt.show()
```

to get the following output with the `pepper` image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to display labels, you should use label map to convert image into superpixels.

```
import numpy as np    
import cv2    
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth

#Loading original image
originImg = cv2.imread('Swimming_Pool.jpg')

# Shape of original image    
originShape = originImg.shape


# Converting image into array of dimension [nb of pixels in originImage, 3]
# based on r g b intensities    
flatImg=np.reshape(originImg, [-1, 3])


# Estimate bandwidth for meanshift algorithm    
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(flatImg, quantile=0.1, n_samples=100)    
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth = bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)

# Performing meanshift on flatImg    
ms.fit(flatImg)

# (r,g,b) vectors corresponding to the different clusters after meanshift    
labels=ms.labels_

# Remaining colors after meanshift    
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_    

# Finding and diplaying the number of clusters    
labels_unique = np.unique(labels)    
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)    
print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)    

# Displaying segmented image    
segmentedImg = np.reshape(labels, originShape[:2])

superpixels=label2rgb(segmentedImg,originImg,kind="'avg'")

cv2.imshow('Image',superpixels)    
cv2.waitKey(0)    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```